# Mysqldump --no create info with drop table

Tags: php, mysql

I have following command in my PHP file:

```
$options = "--compact --add-drop-table --skip-comments --no-create-info --skip-set-charset | sed 's/DROP TABLE IF EXISTS/TRUNCATE TABLE/g'";

//command
$command = '/usr/bin/mysqldump --user='.$user.' --password='.$psw.' --host='.$server.' '.$db.' '.$options.' > /var/www/kukin/backup/SQL/'.$filename;
```

I don't want to have the `CREATE TABLE` command in my sql save, so I add the command `--no-create-info`. But I found out that I also don't have the drop command there. And that is the problem. I want the drop command there, because as you can see in  my example I make the TRUNCATE command from `DROP TABLE` command.

So the simple question is. Can I have the SQL save file with no create table command but with drop table command?

Comment: I don't think so; it would not make a lot of sense to generate sql that drops the table, doesn't create a new one but then behaves as if the table exists.

Comment: @jeroen Yes that sounds logical, I only try it. I also affraid that  my problem has no solution. I have to delete --no-create-info.